# In React, is there a way to apply a filter to responses obtained through fetch?

Tags: reactjs, filter, fetch

Using React 16.12.0.  We have a number of fetch calls that resemble

```
  const handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (password != passConfirm) {
      //handle password doesn't match password confirm on submit
      setErrors({passConfirm: ["Must match password"]})
      return
    }
    fetch(REACT_APP_PROXY + '/users/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': `Token ${sessionStorage.getItem('token')}`},
      body: JSON.stringify({first_name, last_name, username, password, email})
    }).then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('token', response['Refresh-Token'])
        setRedirect(true)
      } else {
        setErrors(response)
        console.log(response)
      }
    })
```

Note the section where we have an ".ok" response

```
sessionStorage.setItem('token', response['Refresh-Token'])
```

We will have a number of these endpoints where we will want to extract this response header and place it in local storage.  Is there a more elegant way of applying a response filter to certain endpoints to implement this behavior as opposed to the way we are doing it now?

Comment: It'd make more sense to set this on the backend than on the frontend. Consider conditionally sending that header, and then set it in this client-side JS only if it exists in the response.

Comment: Use http-only cookies instead. Then the client won't need to keep track of the refresh-tokens at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a possibility for this using fetch except monkey patching fetch itself:

```
const { fetch: originalFetch } = window;

window.fetch = async (...args) => {
  let [url, options] = args;

  // you can run any request logic here

  const response = await originalFetch(url, options);

  // you can run any response logic here

  return response;
};
```

But, there must be someone that already did this, so I stumbled upon this npm library [fetch-intercept](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-intercept) that you can use to do the similar:

```
import fetchIntercept from 'fetch-intercept';

const unregister = fetchIntercept.register({

  response: function (response) {
    // Do something with the response
    if (response.ok) {
      sessionStorage.setItem('token', response['Refresh-Token'])
    }
    return response;
  },

});

// you can call unregister if you don't want run the interceptor anymore
unregister();
```

Please be aware of the following: **You need to require `fetch-intercept` before you use `fetch` the first time**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to switch from `fetch` to `axios`, you can use interceptors and handle it globally.

```js
import axios from 'axios'

axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
  if (response.headers['Refresh-Token']) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('token', response.headers['Refresh-Token'])
  }

  return response
})
```

Reference: https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors

Comment: Thanks but since we have a lot invested in fetch right now, I'm going to keep the scope of this question to fetch calls.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function.

```
async function makeHttpCall(successCallbk) {
    var response = await fetch(...arguments);
    if(response.ok) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('token', response['Refresh-Token']);
        successCallback.call();
    } else {
        setErrors(response);
        console.log(response);
    }
}
```